# auto grow-able text area not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I used auto grow-able textarea in my jsp page to display the output in a formatted way. I expect it to grow in size to fit the height of content to be displayed. But it didn't seem to work. Here is my jsp :-

```
<body onload="init();">
         <div id="mainDivContainer">
            <div id="insideMainDivContainer">
                <a href="InputTest02.html">Back</a>
                <div>
                    <table align="center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Text</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                    <%
                        List<TextBean> list = TextDAO.getData();
                        for (TextBean bean : list) {
                    %>
                     <br/>
                     <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <textarea id="text" name="qa" form="form" rows="10" cols="60"><%=bean.getText() %></textarea>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>

            </table></div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </body>
```

and this is javascript for grow-able text area :-

```
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
}
else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}
function init () {
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    function resize () {
        text.style.height = 'auto';
        text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize () {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change',  resize);
    observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}
```

There are two issues :-

1. The textarea is not expanding in size except for first element.
2. The text in first element is displayed highlighted.
   Here is a screen shot of it :-
   [image].
   I do not understand what is wrong here. All help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line of CSS style to your textarea:

```
textarea { resize: both; }
```

If you want to restrict the direction of resizeablity, just edit the `resize` property:

```
textarea { resize: vertical; }

textarea { resize: horizontal; }
```

Comment: i think your browser doesnt  support css3 unless with this css property a resize icon apears in the right bottom corner of textbox

Comment: according to W3 site this is not supported in IE [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp)

Comment: I tried it on chrome for same result. I want it to automatically expand in height to fit the content.